# in React, returning a state as an array based on the value of an object in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm using React to build out an app that returns the weather using [OpenWeatherAPI Forecast By Hour](https://openweathermap.org/forecast5).

I am successful in pulling my data from OWA and putting it in my `state` with the following code:

```
state = {
        loadedPageForecasts: []
    } 

componentDidMount () {
    //console.log(this.props);

    if (this.props.match.params.id) {
        axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,uk&appid=MYAPIKEY')
        .then(response => {
            //const forecastData = response.data.list.;
            this.setState({loadedPageForecasts: response.data.list});
        });
    }    

}
```

`console.log(loadedPageForecasts)` returns an array with all the data I need, so I'm good there.

Now, I need to filter out from this array and into a new array based on the date that this is. To simplify it, I have just manually selected one of the dates.

I use the below code:

```
const paramsid = this.state.loadedPageForecasts;
        console.log(paramsid);

        let result = paramsid.filter(obj => {
            return obj.type.includes("2018-06-28");
        });

        console.log(result);
```

This returns undefined. So I try below:

```
const paramsid = this.state.loadedPageForecasts;
        console.log(paramsid);

        let result = paramsid.filter(obj => {
            return paramsid.includes("2018-06-28");
        });

        console.log(result);
```

This just returns an empty array.

I think I'm calling the object wrong, but I thought "includes" would scan all objects in the array for this.

I also tried:

```
let result = paramsid.filter(obj => {
            return this.state.dt_txt.includes("2018-06-28");
        });
```

and

```
let result = paramsid.filter(obj => {
            return this.props.dt_txt.includes("2018-06-28");
        });
```

Based on the below screenshot when I do `console.log(paramsid)`[image]

I'm still pretty new to React and I'm trying to get as much practice as I can. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check if the `obj` has a `dt_txt` that includes the date you are looking for in the function given to `filter`:

```
let result = paramsid.filter(obj => {
  return obj.dt_txt.includes("2018-06-28");
});
```

Comment: @logos_164 You have no `type` property on your objects in the array.

Comment: Ahh okay that was my mistake is I thought .type was a call to ANY object within the object, I took that from another answer and must have not read it all the way. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
let result = paramsid.filter(obj => {
  return obj.dt_txt.includes("2018-06-28");
});
```

Also, make sure you are calling this after the `setState` is successful (In a `setState callback`). It'll make sure that you are performing the following operation in an asynchronous manner.